# Adding a structure to a NSDictionary

Tags: ios, avfoundation, video-processing

I am creating a `CMVideoFormatDescriptionRef` out of thin air using this code:

```
  CMVideoDimensions dimensions = {
    .width = width,
    .height = height
  };

  CMVideoFormatDescriptionRef videoInfo = NULL;

  NSDictionary *options2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @(YES), kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                           @(YES), kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
                           dimensions, kCVImageBufferDisplayDimensionsKey,
                            nil];
  CFDictionaryRef dictOptionsRef = (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)options2;

  CMFormatDescriptionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCMMediaType_Video, 'brga', dictOptionsRef, &videoInfo);
```

I need to pass that dictionary to `CMFormatDescriptionCreate`.

The problem is the last line

```
dimensions, kCVImageBufferDisplayDimensionsKey,
```

This is not the correct way to add `dimensions` to that dict. It crashes the app.

I have tried to wrap the whole thing on a `NSValue` using this:

```
NSValue *miValue = [NSValue value: &dimensions
                     withObjCType:@encode(CMVideoDimensions)];
```

It works in theory, no crash, but `videoInfo` is not created correctly (OSStatus -12731). If I remove this last line from the dictionary, `videoInfo` is created but has no definition for the dimensions, that are assumed to be 0x0 pixels, or `codecType`. See below:

```
<CMVideoFormatDescription 0x17044c270 [0x1b0330bb8]> {
    mediaType:'vide' 
    mediaSubType:'brga' 
    mediaSpecific: {
        codecType: 0        dimensions: 0 x 0    <--HERE!!!
    } 
    extensions: {<CFBasicHash 0x17086dcc0 [0x1b0330bb8]>{type = immutable dict, count = 4,
entries =>
    0 : <CFString 0x1aa9427c8 [0x1b0330bb8]>{contents = "CVImageBufferYCbCrMatrix"} = <CFString 0x1aa942808 [0x1b0330bb8]>{contents = "ITU_R_601_4"}
    3 : <CFString 0x1aa942c68 [0x1b0330bb8]>{contents = "CGImageCompatibility"} = <CFBoolean 0x1b0331110 [0x1b0330bb8]>{value = true}
    5 : <CFString 0x1aa9428a8 [0x1b0330bb8]>{contents = "CVImageBufferColorPrimaries"} = <CFString 0x1aa9427e8 [0x1b0330bb8]>{contents = "ITU_R_709_2"}
    6 : <CFString 0x1aa942c48 [0x1b0330bb8]>{contents = "CGBitmapContextCompatibility"} = <CFBoolean 0x1b0331110 [0x1b0330bb8]>{value = true}
}
}
}
```

A `CMVideoFormatDescriptionRef` from a regular `CMSampleBufferRef` shows `codecType` as `BGRA` and the regular dimensions of the frame, 1920x1080, for example.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `kCVImageBufferDisplayDimensionsKey` header file says the key's value is a

> // CFDictionary with the following two keys

`kCVImageBufferDisplayWidthKey` and `kCVImageBufferDisplayHeightKey`, both of which are `CFNumber`s.

You're passing `CMVideoDimensions` instead, so change that to

```
NSDictionary *dimensions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@(width), kCVImageBufferDisplayWidthKey, @(height), kCVImageBufferDisplayHeightKey];
```